# change background color of treeview control not found?

Tags: c#, css, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

First Xamarin app attempt...Using the treeview example from https://github.com/danvanderboom/Xamarin-Forms-TreeView to include a treeview search into the project.

Although I would like to remove the grey background color in the treeview. Iv used a program to get the color which is #808080   I cant find this color anywhere in the project...So where is the color coming from? I then searched the entire project for color and looked through each one... I cant find anything which is producing this. any advice? Currently testing on Android

[image]

Comment: That's the `backgroundColor` of `Grid` in `DemoTreeCardView.xaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below fine, set the BackgroundColor property to Transparent or remove it to get your code working.

https://github.com/danvanderboom/Xamarin-Forms-TreeView/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.TreeView/HighEnergy.TreeView.Demo/DemoModule/DemoTreeCardView.xaml

[image: Issue Image]

Comment: @John, If my reply helps you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks :)

Comment: Brilliant...thanks for your help Harikrishnan...Much appreciated!